# How can you have multiple logic app ARM templates deployed in a single "Deploy" action in Visual Studio?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2019, azure-logic-apps

How can you have multiple logic app ARM templates deployed in a single "Deploy" action in Visual Studio?

Using the current version (2.23.1) of the "Azure Logic Apps Tools for Visual Studio 2019" extension (as of 1/1/2021). Create a new "Azure Resource Group" project, and add a "Logic App" template to it. Use the "Deploy" action on the project, and the logic app deploys OK. Can add a second logic app to the original JSON file, and then build & deploy it fine.

You can use the Cloud Explorer to download an existing logic app into a local JSON file, and include it in the VS project, set it to "Content" and its included in the build OK.

But it does **NOT** get deployed

I can see the command in the Output window for the original JSON using the `Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1` script to do the deployment

```
...\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1'
-StorageAccountName ''
-ResourceGroupName 'logic-app-rg'
-ResourceGroupLocation 'northeurope'
-TemplateFile '...\logicapp.json'
-TemplateParametersFile '...\logicapp.parameters.json'
-ArtifactStagingDirectory '.'
-DSCSourceFolder '.\DSC'
```

But I can't work out how to get the second JSON file with the downloaded from Azure logic app to be included in the deployment?

*... I can use the Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 in the PowerShell console to do a deployment, but that's a second manual step to remember to do each time*

Comment: If you want to deploy multiple templates at one time, you can try to use nested template : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates.

Comment: @JimXu Thanks for the pointer ... main issue with that approach is I'd have to mess around with existing code ... I was hoping to just add in the new JSON, and do "something" to get it to deploy along with the other JSON